# Is it possible to set a shuttercallback for the default camera app

Tags: android

i know i can call the default camera app by doing

```
    Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();
    callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

    startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP);
```

but i want to perform an action when the user takes an image... is that possible 
or do i need to implement a camera preview on my own app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by performing an action, you mean you want to change the behavior the camera app, you cannot. You will need to create your own custom camera app.

Comment: need 10 minutes before i can accept an answer, no worries you will get your rep XD

Comment: It is not really about the rep. It is about showing that this question was answered.